# UPPER() for special characters (ascii 181)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In Wikipedia the Greek letter Mu (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)) has different characters for uppercase and lowercase. In T-SQL when using the `upper()` function it ignores this and it doesn't get converted. However in other systems like informatica it does know how to output the correct character. How do I get the T-SQL version of this. I've tried using collation on the column with no luck.

for example (I've tried all the collation in `sys.fn_helpcollations()`:

```
select  
  upper(MERCHANT_NAME collate SQL_Hungarian_CP1250_CI_AS) as converted
from my test table
```

but it outputs: `µ`
not what I expect: `M`

Comment: why do you use Hungarian for Greek letters?

Comment: that was just an example. i actually had a script that tried all the collations in the sys.fn_helpcollations() view. None of them worked. Maybe is the way i applied the collate in the SQL that could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASCII char 181 (micro sign) do not have an uppercase form.
Greek lowercase letter Mu should be represented by UTF-8 pair 206 188. This one is correctly converted to uppercase Mu by function UPPER.
If you have to use UPPER function, you need to use proper UTF codes for Greek letters, not math symbols.

From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)) you have following 5 symbols:

- greek capital letter mu (UTF-8: 206 156, not exists in Windows 1525)
- greek small letter mu (UTF-8: 206 188, not exists in Windows 1525)
- micro sign (UTF-8: 194 181, Windows 1525: 181)
- coptic capital letter mi
- coptic small letter mi

Greek small letter mu and micro sign looks exactly the same.

Comment: I think it does have an upper case form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter) says so LOL, and Informatica does it as well. 

How do i apply the "proper UTF codes" can that be done on the fly using t-sql?

Comment: How the data are loaded into this table?

Comment: ok i think i understand this now. So sql server is right by not converting it to uppercase form. Its somehow reading it incorrectly

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate @Piotr's answer:

`with cte (x) as (
    select N'µ'
    union all
    select N'μ'
    )
select x, UNICODE(x), UPPER(x)
from cte`

results in

```
µ   181    µ
μ   956    Μ
```

OP actually contains NCHAR(181)

Answer (score -1):

Likely has to do with language settings not connecting the two. In the mean time you can utilize replace

```
SELECT REPLACE(MERCHANT_NAME COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'µ', 'M') 
from my test table
```

Comment: i probably need something that would work for other characters as well.